# Use PHP to Read Mysql my.cnf

Tags: php, my.cnf

PHP's `ini_get` function is really useful for double-checking my settings for me.

Example:

```
<?php 
   echo 'post_max_size = ' . ini_get('post_max_size'); // 8MB
?>
```

How can PHP read the `my.cnf` settings file?

I've looked for a similar function that can display the settings to me, but I'm not finding one.

I usually need to validate variables like: `innodb_file_per_table`, `default-time-zone`, and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the my.cnf via PHP you could use [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) to open and read it.

It should allow you to put the different sections directly into an associative array.

Something like this:

```
$settings = parse_ini_file('/path/to/my.cnf',true);
```

Comment: BUT, php does not honour # as a comment marker, so can not be used on all mysql config files. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40335851/deprecated-comments-starting-with-are-deprecated