# Deprecated: Comments starting with '#' are deprecated

Tags: php

I'm running lighttpd with the user `ab` I have googled about this problem before and all the solutions say that I have to change all lines starting with `#` in `/etc/php.ini` to `;` but in my `php.ini` file, there's no line starting with `#`, everything is already using `;` instead of `#`. The error says:

```
Deprecated: Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in Unknown on line 11 in /www/log.php on line 224
Deprecated: Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in Unknown on line 11 in /www/log.php on line 175
```

The error of `log.php` is located in this line:

```
$array = parse_ini_string(str_replace(' ', '=', file_get_contents('/home/ab/config')));
$profile = parse_ini_string(str_replace(' ', '=', file_get_contents('/home/ab/profiles/'.$array['profile'])));
```

How can I solve this ?

**UPDATE:**
Yes my files contain `#` they look like this:

```
enable_iprule 'no'
enable_qoshunter 'no'
ip_rule ''
apn_modem 'internet'
auto_kodok 'no'
use_vpn 'no'
use_ssh 'no'
proxy_ip ''
proxy_port ''
payload_inject ''
#info 'update 01/01/14'
#info 'koneksi standart menggunakan kuota'
```

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: You are parsing a couple of files with `parse_ini_string`, right? I'm asking whether these files contain `#`-comments. In other words, you should post the contents of these files here. Also, there may be files included into the main `php.ini`. However, `parse_ini_string` seems to just ignore `#`-comments

Comment: you may have muliple php(et al).ini files used, phpinfo() will list them alll

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov Yes, the files contain `#` so how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are [likely running PHP version 5.6](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c0891d9326dc6085626a9d5cb9fcb7e62902aedc/Zend/zend_ini_scanner.l#L642) or older, since PHP 7 [interprets the `#` comments as ini directives](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/83391b5518619cce7d2a1baf5a4434b1690a33d1) in the `parse_ini_string` function:

```
$ini = <<<'EOINI'
payload_inject '10'
#info 'abc def'
#info 'xyz 123'
EOINI;
$array = parse_ini_string(str_replace(' ', '=', $ini));
print_r($array);
```

*Output*

```
Array
(
    [payload_inject] => 10
    [#info] => xyz=123
)
```

So you should replace the `#` characters at the beginnings of the lines with `;`:

```
$ini = file_get_contents($filename);
$ini = preg_replace('/^\s*#/m', ';', $ini);
$array = parse_ini_string(str_replace(' ', '=', $ini));
```

where `m` is the multiline [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).